# Make toggle open only the actively clicked button, not all toggles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Right now I've got a toggle that when you click it opens every toggle that is named 'content'. How can I make it so that the toggles are opened individually?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4N6xj/embedded/result/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var $content = $(".content").hide();
 $(".toggle").on("click", function(e){   
      $content.slideToggle(200);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Target the [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) `.content` element from the clicked `.toggle`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".content").hide();

    $(".toggle").on("click", function(e){   
        $(this).next('.content').slideToggle(200);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4N6xj/1/)